# I told him I was otherwise engaged. (In what context does this sentence be used?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I told him I was otherwise engaged.

Could you explain in what context this sentence can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone has invited you to a social event or asked you to do something at a certain time. You couldn't, because you had to be somewhere else (or you didn't want to so you pretended that you couldn't). Now you are telling someone else what you said.